# How can i make automatically append divs with based on screen resolution both sides of my text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying make it as a name of table besides table name red color dashes is there i want to append this dashes dynamically based on screen size . on both sides of my text . sorry for my bad English. give me a Suggestion how to make it ?

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  background:blue;
  text-align:center;
}
.container span{
  color:#fff;
  
}
.container .dashes{
 display:inline-block;
 width:5px;
 height:5px;
 background:red;
  vertical-align:middle;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="dashes"></div>
  <span>Name</span>
  <div class="dashes"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: use :before and :after

Comment: i want meany dashes depends upon container width

Comment: ............text..............

Comment: based on screen resolution it will change automatically

Comment: that is easy use a dashed border :)

Comment: how can i ? i don't have idea give me a suggestion .

Comment: give me a example

Comment: see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_border-style2

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `.dashes` width as per your screen size using media-query.

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  background:blue;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.container span{
  color:#fff;
  
}
.container .dashes{
 display:inline-block;
 width:200px;
 height:0;
 background:red;
  vertical-align:middle;
 border: 2px dashed blue;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dashes"></div>
    <span>Name</span>
  <div class="dashes"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It Is Not Working Proporly

Comment: Why what's the problem?

Comment: why did you do the dashes blue and the background red ? :)))))

Comment: Backgorund red because @S.R wants the red dashes and border blue because it is showing like there is nothing just for transparency visualization :)